# pycharm coding error message. numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, append

I wrote a code like this:

```
for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
    x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0])
```

but then it keep return an error message of

```
x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0])
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'"
```

anyone can help to see any problem in there? thank you

Comment: at a first glance, the error message says x_train is an np array, therefore list.append does not apply to it

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory, there *is* no `array.append(...)` function. Use `numpy.append(array, array_to_append)` instead.

Always check the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) for correct usage first.